# Animate tab bar shape created using UIBezierPath() based on selected index

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar, uibezierpath

I have created a tab Bar shape using `UIBezierPath()`. Im new to creating shapes so in the end I got the desired shape closer to what I wanted, not perfect but it works. It's a shape which has a wave like top, so on the left side there is a crest and second half has a trough. This is the code that I used to create the shape:

```
 func createPath() -> CGPath {
        let height: CGFloat = 40.0 // Height of the wave-like curve
        let extraHeight: CGFloat = -20.0 // Additional height for top left and top right corners
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        let width = self.frame.width
        // Creating a wave-like top edge for tab bar starting from left side
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: extraHeight)) // Start at top left corner with extra height
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: width/2, y: extraHeight), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: width/4, y: extraHeight - height))
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: extraHeight), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: width*3/4, y: extraHeight + height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: self.frame.height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height))
        path.close()
        return path.cgPath
    }
```

Above im using -20 so that shape stays above bounds of tab bar and second wave's trough stays above the icons of tab bar. Here is the desired result:

[image: A tab bar with four tabs: a house icon, a cloud-and-rain icon, a speedometer icon, and a head with headphones icon. The window background is red. The tab bar background is white and the top edge of the tab bar is curved like one cycle of a sine wave. The house icon is selected.]

This was fine until I was asked to animate the shape on pressing tab bar items. So if I press second item, the crest should be above second item and if fourth, then it should be above fourth item. So I created a function called `updateShape(with selectedIndex: Int)` and called it in `didSelect` method of my TabBarController. In that im passing index of the selected tab and based on that creating new path and removing old and replacing with new one. Here is how im doing it:

```
    func updateShape(with selectedIndex: Int) {
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        let height: CGFloat = 40.0
        let extraHeight: CGFloat = -20.0
        let width = self.frame.width

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: extraHeight))
        if selectedIndex == 0 {
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: width / 2, y: extraHeight), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: width / 4, y: extraHeight - height))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: extraHeight), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: width / 2 + width / 4, y: extraHeight + height))
        }
        else if selectedIndex == 1 {
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: width / 2 + width / 4, y: extraHeight), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: width / 4 + width / 4, y: extraHeight - height))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: extraHeight), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: width * 3 / 4 + width / 4, y: extraHeight + height))
        }
        else if selectedIndex == 2 {
            let xShift = width / 4
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: width / 2 + xShift, y: extraHeight), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: width / 8 + xShift, y: extraHeight + height))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: extraHeight), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: width * 7 / 8 + xShift, y: extraHeight - height))
        }
        else {
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: width / 2, y: extraHeight), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: width / 4, y: extraHeight + height))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: extraHeight), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: width / 2 + width / 4, y: extraHeight - height))
        }
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: self.frame.height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height))
        path.close()

        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.secondarySystemBackground.cgColor

        if let oldShapeLayer = self.shapeLayer {
            self.layer.replaceSublayer(oldShapeLayer, with: shapeLayer)
        } else {
            self.layer.insertSublayer(shapeLayer, at: 0)
        }

        self.shapeLayer = shapeLayer
    }
```

And calling it like this:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        let tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar as! CustomTabBar
        guard let index = viewControllers?.firstIndex(of: viewController) else {
            return
        }

        tabBar.updateShape(with: index)
    }
```

This is working fine as you can see below but the problem is I learned creating shapes just now and creating that wave based on width of screen so the crest and trough are exactly half the width of frame so I was able to do it for `FourthViewController` too and got this:

[image: The same tab bar as before. Now the window background is brown, the head-with-headphones tab is selected, and the sine wave is mirror-imaged so the trough is on the left and the peak is on the right.]

But the problem arises for remaining 2 indices. Im not able to create same wave which looks like the crest is moving above second or third item instead I get something like this:

[image: The same tab bar as above. Now the speedometer tab is selected, the window background is green, and the sine wave is shifted so the trough is roughly over the cloud-with-rain icon and the peak is off the right side of the screen.]

It doesn't look like other to waves showing the hump over third item. Also my code is strictly based on 4 items and was wondering if Im asked to add 1 more item so tab bar has 5 or 6 items, it would be trouble. Is there any way to update my function that creates new shapes based on index of tab bar or can anyone help me just create shapes for remaining two items? The shape should look same just the hump should exactly be over the selected item.

Comment: Does this animate at the moment? If you set the path of an existing shapelayer to a new path, it will interpolate between the two if possible

Comment: (I know that’s not the question you’re asking here, but I’m interested anyway)

Comment: In your first screenshot, the crest of the wave isn’t directly over the selected item, and the curve starts to rise again on the right side - if you extend that line, would it go to the same height as the original crest?

Comment: no it does not. I have not added any animation. first Im just trying to nail the shape. you are correct its not exactly above the first item in first screen shot but still looks ok and I was wondering if I could just shift it to a little right for 2nd item and more right for third and so on and  it would still look ok. animation comes later, first I just want to have correct shapes for all selected indices. I just created the repo. here is the link for it, you can check yourself. its bland so far: https://github.com/shwaitkumar/WavyTabBar.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want something like this:

[image: A tab bar with four icons. The top of the tab bar is an attenuated sinusoidal curve with a major peak above the selected tab icon. As different tabs are selected, the curve animates to keep the peak above the selected tab.]

Here's how I did it. First, I made a `WaveView` that draws this curve:

[image: A curve with a peak in the center and a smaller peaks on each side.]

Notice that the major peak exactly in the center. Here's the source code:

```
class WaveView: UIView {
    var trough: CGFloat {
        didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
    }

    var color: UIColor {
        didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
    }

    init(trough: CGFloat, color: UIColor = .white) {
        self.trough = trough
        self.color = color

        super.init(frame: .zero)

        contentMode = .redraw
        isOpaque = false
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        guard let gc = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

        let bounds = self.bounds
        let size = bounds.size
        gc.translateBy(x: bounds.origin.x, y: bounds.origin.y)

        gc.move(to: .init(x: 0, y: size.height))

        gc.saveGState(); do {
            // Transform the geometry so the bounding box of the curve
            // is (-1, 0) to (+1, +1), with the y axis going up.
            gc.translateBy(x: bounds.midX, y: trough)
            gc.scaleBy(x: bounds.size.width * 0.5, y: -trough)

            // Now draw the curve.
            for x in stride(from: -1, through: 1, by: 2 / size.width) {
                let y = (cos(2.5 * .pi * x) + 1) / 2 * (1 - x * x)
                gc.addLine(to: .init(x: x, y: y))
            }
        }; gc.restoreGState()

        // The geometry is restored.
        gc.addLine(to: .init(x: size.width, y: size.height))
        gc.closePath()

        gc.setFillColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
        gc.fillPath()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") }
}
```

Then, I made a subclass of `UITabBarController` named `WaveTabBarController` that creates a `WaveView` and puts it behind the tab bar. It makes the `WaveView` exactly twice the width of the tab bar, and sets the x coordinate of the `WaveView`'s frame such that the peak is above the selected tab item. Here's the source code:

```
class WaveTabBarController: UITabBarController {
    let waveView = WaveView(trough: 20)

    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        if superclass!.instancesRespond(to: #selector(UITabBarDelegate.tabBar(_:didSelect:))) {
            super.tabBar(tabBar, didSelect: item)
        }
        view.setNeedsLayout()
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        let shouldAnimate: Bool

        if waveView.superview != view {
            view.insertSubview(waveView, at: 0)
            shouldAnimate = false
        } else {
            shouldAnimate = true
        }

        let tabBar = self.tabBar
        let w: CGFloat

        if let selected = tabBar.selectedItem, let items = tabBar.items {
            w = (CGFloat(items.firstIndex(of: selected) ?? 0) + 0.5) / CGFloat(items.count) - 1
        } else {
            w = -1
        }

        let trough = waveView.trough
        let tabBarFrame = view.convert(tabBar.bounds, from: tabBar)
        let waveFrame = CGRect(
            x: tabBarFrame.origin.x + tabBarFrame.size.width * w,
            y: tabBarFrame.origin.y - trough,
            width: 2 * tabBarFrame.size.width,
            height: tabBarFrame.size.height + trough
        )

        guard waveFrame != waveView.frame else {
            return
        }

        if shouldAnimate {
            // Don't animate during the layout pass.
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [waveView] in
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut) {
                    waveView.frame = waveFrame
                }
            }
        } else {
            waveView.frame = waveFrame
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was my first thought but now I’m wondering about a cooler animation where one peak comes down while another comes up…

Comment: ok giving it a try soon. Will update you and if I execute if properly, I will mark the solution as correct directly

Comment: ok I could not implement even tho I think the blueprint above is correct

Comment: okay exactly as what I required. tweaked the code little to get different wavy pattern and looks even better.  it is totally different from my code but after tweaking I now understand how it works and it seems easier than using UIBezerPath()